# Differentiation help needed

Tags: calculus

I am having some trouble on my math assignment. The question has three parts, and I think have the correct answer on the first two parts, but the last one, I'm having trouble with. It says to consider the curve given by $$x² + 4y² = 7 + 3xy$$

For the first part, it says to find the derivative. I found the derivative to be $$\frac{3y-2x}{8y-3x}$$ I am sure that this part is right.

The second part says to show that there is a point $P$ with x-coordinate $3$ at which the line tangent to the currve at $P$ is horizontal, and to find the $y$ coordinate of $P$. I set the derivative equal to $0$, and found the point to be $(3,2)$.

The last part is where I am having trouble. It says to find the second derivative of $dy/dx$ at the point $P$ found in part 2 $(3,2)$. It asks whether the curve has a local maximum or local minimum, or neither at point $P$, and to justify. I am confused on how to differentiate the derivative, because it has y values in it. I have learned implicit differentiation, but in this case there is no $y'$, so do I treat it as if it were an $x$?

I am not sure where to go from this point, and would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's okay; we can just do implicit differentiation again. Because I hate fractions, I'll rewrite it as:
$$
(8y - 3x)y' = 3y - 2x
$$
Differentiating, we get:
\begin{align*}
(8y' - 3)y' + (8y - 3x)y'' &= 3y' - 2 \\
y'' &= \frac{-8(y')^2 + 6(y') - 2}{8y - 3x} \\
\end{align*}
Now since $\left.\frac{dy}{dx}\right|_{(x,y) = (3, 2)} = 0$, it follows that:
$$
\left.\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}\right|_{(x,y) = (3, 2)} = \frac{-8(0)^2 + 6(0) - 2}{8(2) - 3(3)}
= \frac{-2}{7} < 0
$$
Hence, by the Second Derivative Test, the curve has a local maximum at $P$.

Comment: more generally, even if $y'\not=0$ at some other point you may find $y''$ anyway using implicit differentiation, and any time $y'$ occurs in your expression, just replace it with what you already found for $y'$ before, that is with $\frac{3y-2x}{8y-3x}$ in your case